# How to sort SKProduct by Apple ID

Tags: ios, sorting, in-app-purchase, nsarray, skproduct

I'd like to sort those products retrieved from itunesconnect.apple.com by `AppleID` that are online generated automatically.

I checked `SKProduct`, but only find these propertis, none of which are referred to `Apple ID`,

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSString *localizedDescription 
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSString *localizedTitle 
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSDecimalNumber *price 
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSLocale *priceLocale 
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSString *productIdentifier 
@property(nonatomic, readonly, getter=isDownloadable) BOOL downloadable 
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *downloadContentLengths 
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSString *downloadContentVersion
```

Does anyone know about it?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean when say `AppleID`? Actually `productIdentifier` is those identifier that makes product unique.

Comment: Apple ID is a 9-digit number assigned automatically when creating 'productIdentifier' . it's unique too.

Comment: screenshot of Apple id attached.

Comment: It seems that it is impossible to retrieve this data. Why do you need sort by AppleId? Why can't you use other properties?

Comment: Cause I'd like to list products in line with sequences of products added. Later, I would add in-app products online , then make sure them shown at the bottom of table view .

Comment: In this case you could use productId, name it in your special manner and it will be added to bottom. ProductId also isn't shown to user. I understand that it isn't clear solution but it seems that it the most optimized way to achieve your target.